# Cocoapod subspec dependency not adding header/library search paths

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I'm writing a Cocoapods podspec for a Swift library (https://github.com/promotedai/ios-metrics-sdk). One of our clients asked us to add Firebase Analytics tracking to the internals of this library. As a result, in the [podspec](https://github.com/promotedai/ios-metrics-sdk/blob/main/PromotedAIMetricsSDK.podspec), I broke the Firebase dependency into a subspec.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'PromotedAIMetricsSDK'
  ...

  s.subspec 'FirebaseAnalytics' do |a|
    a.source_files = ['Sources/PromotedFirebaseAnalytics/**/*.{h,m,swift}']
    a.dependency 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 7.11.0'
    a.dependency 'PromotedAIMetricsSDK/Core'
  end
end
```

The problem I ran into was that the above subspec neither builds nor passes `pod lib lint`. The build complained about a missing Firebase framework, and the lint step complained about the same thing. I had to add the following `xcconfig` to the subspec to get things working.

```
analytics_xcconfig = {
  'USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources"',
  'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseAnalytics" "${PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleUtilities" "${PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR}/nanopb"',
  'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework "FirebaseAnalytics" -framework "GoogleUtilities" -framework "nanopb"'
}

s.subspec 'FirebaseAnalytics' do |a|
  a.source_files = ['Sources/PromotedFirebaseAnalytics/**/*.{h,m,swift}']
  a.dependency 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 7.11.0'
  a.dependency 'PromotedAIMetricsSDK/Core'
  a.pod_target_xcconfig = analytics_xcconfig
end
```

While the above configuration allows the subspec to build and pass lint validation, it defeats the purpose of having a package manager take care of these dependencies. I have other subspecs that pull in dependencies that don't encounter the same problem. Also, pulling in `Firebase/Analytics` directly in the app's `Podfile` works fine.

Am I missing something? Is there a reason why `Firebase/Analytics` requires this `xcconfig` hack when building from a subspec of a podspec? Can I get rid of this hack somehow?

For a demonstration of this problem, pull the above repo and remove the `a.pod_target_xcconfig = ...` lines from the `FirebaseAnalytics` subspec, then run `pod lib lint`. Commit `67cb6173ee0f43b33cfb726b6337cc14463d220b` in the repo demonstrates a similar problem where the linker can't find the FirebaseAnalytics framework (run `pod lib lint` on that commit).

I'm using Cocoapods 1.10.1, Xcode 12.5, and macOS 11.3.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks! This is the only working solution i found to use FirebaseAnalytics in a subspec of a development pod.